# Get row of the error when using converters with read_csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a csv file containing **Dates**, infos such as **Countries** (which can only take values within a predefined list), and I am currently using the **converters** parameter to make some sanity checks as below:

```
import pandas as pd

def datesCheck(x):
    #do some checks and return the formated date
    pass

def countriesCheck(x):
    if x in countriesList:
        return x
    else:
    raise ValueError, x + ' is not a recognised country'

df = pd.read_csv('myCsvFile.csv', converters={'Dates': datesCheck, 'Countries': countriesCheck})
```

What I am wondering is if there is a way to get the number of the row which raises (or the first one) a ValueError if any, so I can open the csv file and change it quickly.

Thank you for your help. Have a good week-end!

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a counter variable and count the rows and raise the row causing error:

```
import pandas as pd

current_row = 0

def datesCheck(x):
    current_row += 1
    #do some checks and return the formated date
    # if date ok do nothing
    # else raise ValueError, 'Error Row = ' + str(current_row )
    pass

def countriesCheck(x):
    if x in countriesList:
        return x
    else:
    raise ValueError, x + ' is not a recognised country in row = ' + str(current_row)

df = pd.read_csv('myCsvFile.csv', converters={'Dates': datesCheck, 'Countries': countriesCheck})
```

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering if there was a better way, as with this logic I'll need a counter variable for each column. I would guess that the algorithm behind converters has the row info...

Comment: Other way is,  which ever row column value did not parse, set a default value or set it as NaN, and after completing reading, filter for all the NaN values and get the corresponding index and that shall be the row+1 in csv file.

Comment: Sounds like a very good idea! That way I can throw an error with all the rows which are inconsistent at once. Thank you.